# Design of SMPS for running 10 bldc motors

Tags: ac, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, converter

I want to run 10 motors, each motor has specification of max 70 V and max current 160 amps. My doubt is, is it possible to build SMPS for these purpose. If not what would be the best alternative. I have very limited knowledge in this field, please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Almost anything mentioning "160 Amps" would make may say: leave that to the professionals. At currents like that you **really** need to know what you're doing. The fact that you have to ask and also that you admit that you have "very limited knowledge" means that this is not something **you** can do successfully on your own. Sure you can learn how to do it. It will take you several years of working with the professionals that do this kind of thing already.

Comment: You have asked a broad question with very few details. Each motor needs its own control unit. If you need something additional to match the motor voltage to the supply voltage, you have probably not selected the right motors or the right power source. Voting to close.

Comment: 10*70V*160A = 112kW. You realize this is about 20 times the max power typically allowed for a house?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is nowhere near complete, and indicates such a lack of knowledge of the fundamentals that the only practical answer is *"Don't try this.  Go buy a solution."*

You say each motor requires 70 V at 160 A.  That's 11.2 kW *per motor*, for a total of over 100 kW.  This is way past amateur-level electronics.  This is the kind of problem that requires specialization even among professionals.  I have a masters degree in electrical engineering and have been designing circuits professionally for nearly 40 years, and I would refer such a problem to someone that specializes in the right kind of high power engineering.

You talk about a "SMPS", but haven't even mentioned what form the power takes going into this SMPS.  At these power levels, you're dealing with 3 phase AC feeds, and have to work with your local power provider.  This is way past just plugging something into a socket.

Again, get the right kind of professional to address whatever problem you really have.  You are in over your head. *Way* over your head.